# php wont redirect after form submission

Tags: php, html, forms, redirect, submit

I am trying to get my page to redirect after deleting a record from the database but it wont redirect. It is echoing out text and also deleting the record but it just reloads me on the same page with a form that no longer has information in it.

Here is the button im using

```
echo '<form>';
echo '<br /><br /><input style="cursor:pointer" class="button" type="submit" value="Delete Event" name="delete" id="delete" />';
echo '</form>';
```

Here is the PHP im using to delete the row from the DB

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])){
        $mysqli->query('DELETE FROM information WHERE id = '.intval($_GET['id']));
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
```

I have no idea whats wrong with it.

Comment: I think there is an issue in your form. You test isset on $_POST but query using a $_GET

Comment: am i not right in saying that when i hit the submit button it posts the name of the button? being delete? Then i am deleting the record from the id that is in the url that is displaying the information in the database row so i am using $_GET to get that id back so the query knows which row to delete.

Comment: Form submits are either get or post. I don't think you can use method POST and retrieve data with $_GET (to my knowledge anyway). In other words, if it's a POST there is nothing in link

Comment: am sure you set your header already. show entire code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header doesn't work, probably because there's already another one.
I suggest you to use a little part of Javascript:

`if (isset($_POST['delete'])){
        $mysqli->query('DELETE FROM information WHERE id = '.intval($_GET['id']));
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href = 'index.php'</script>";
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Your form tag is completely empty. You check if `$_POST["delete"]` is set, but you haven't even specified the method of communication between your form and your PHP file on your form. Try changing your starting form tag to this:

```
<form method = "POST" action = "YOUR PHP FILE.php">
```

Your PHP file seems fine as long as `index.php` is on the same level as the form.

You can also redirect your page to somewhere else this way:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=index.php"/>"
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that both the code snippets are present in a single PHP file. Then, your form will by default post to the same file using GET method.
Change your PHP code to look like this:-

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['delete'])){
    $mysqli->query('DELETE FROM information WHERE id ='.intval($_GET['id']));
    header('Location: index.php');
}


echo '<form>';
echo '<br /><br /><input style="cursor:pointer" class="button" type="submit" value="Delete Event" name="delete" id="delete" />';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form>
    Delete id <input type = "text" name ="deleteid" id ="deleteid"/>
    <input type ="submit" name = "submit" />
    </form>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $id = $_POST['deleteid'];
    $query = "DELETE FROM information WHERE id = $id";
    //rest Execute the query
      header('Location: xyx.php'); 
    }
    <?
```

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to include an explanation of how your code solves the problem at hand.